# I want this function to produce only one answer but for some reason it provides a whole list. How can i make it to produce one answer?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I need some help. I have done regression and am using those results to multiple against numbers to produce a function and so now I expected one result. However, there are multiple results.

```py
IDCM = [est.params['VDD-CM(V)']* vcm] + [est.params['CLK_IN(Hz)']* clk_in] + [est.params['VDD-CL(V)']* vcl] + [est.params['const']]

IDCM
```

[Regression answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvbXm.png)
[est.params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1n3C.png)

Comment: What are the variables in that expression?  `est`, `est.parames`, `vcm` etc.

Comment: those are the answers to an ols regresssion that I did! vcm is a column of numbers as well as clk_in and vcl. I have attached the est.params too now, sorry about that

Comment: Description of variables using terms like `list`, numpy array, shape, dtype, dataframe would be more useful.  A `column of numbers` is too vague.

Comment: the variables are a data frame such as vcm being .85-1.20 in increments of .05, clk_in being 0,12288000,6000000 and also vcl being .75-1.20 in increments of .05

Comment: What's the purpose of including all expressions in list brackets?  Do you realize that `[1]+[2]` produces `[1,2]`?

Comment: I did not know that. How will I be able to fix that? Do I just remove the brackets? If I remove the brackets will they still be in the order that I am telling them? Like following pemdas?

Comment: What are you trying to?  Add some numbers?  Produce list or tuple of numbers?  I may be too nice here.  Often we expect a concrete example, AND an example of desired output.  You many need to read up on [mcve].

Comment: when I remove the list brackets so than it will look like this est.params['VDD-CM(V)'] * vcm... the answer produces a data frame with a whole bunch of nan values

Comment: I am basically trying to add all the numbers up and have one final answer instead of a list of values. Kind of like 2+2 = 4 and not have like a list.

Comment: when I try to add all the numbers in the list it produces a data frame with nan values which doesnt make any sense

Comment: Look at `est.params['VDD-CM(V)']` - type, dtype(s), shape.  Likewise `vcm`.  Then their product.  Standard debugging.  If the whole expression produces something you don't understand or want, start looking at smaller pieces.